# Is There A Way Of Using the_post_thumbnail() to Pull In A Specific Image From The Media Library

Tags: images, page-template

I currently have a custom theme with some images in a separate image folder and I pull them into the frontend with the `echo get_theme_file_uri('/img/image-name.jpg')` which works as expected.

I would like to be able to add images from the media library, I know I can do this with `the_post_thumbnail()`, but this obviously pulls in the post thumbnail relating to a post, whereas I've designed a page that uses 4 different images.

Is there a template tag that pulls in an image out of the media library onto a page where I can use the image's ID, so you get the benefits `the_post_thumbnail()` brings in terms of sizing images etc ?

Any help would be amazing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent function for arbitrary images that aren't the post thumbnail is [`wp_get_attachment_image()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image/). It works similarly, but you need to pass the attachment ID, and there's an `$icon` argument that doesn't really do much:

```
echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, 'large', false, [] );
```

Comment: Hi @JacobPeattie - when i do that it doesn't pull the image in. The image I'm using has a post ID of 142 so I've done `wp_get_attachment_image( 142, 'large', false, [] );` but it doesn't work. Have I done that correctly?

Comment: Did you make sure to `echo`? And are you sure 142 is the is of the image, and not a post that it’s attached to?

Comment: Oh boy. I was missing the echo. It's been a very long day. Thanks for you help Jacob.